# Iframes not working

Tags: html, iframe, frame

I'm trying to get Iframes to work. I'm running safari, so it is compatible, but when I test it, it comes up blank. 
Code:

`<iframe src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="300">`

`<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>`

`</iframe>`

I took the code directly from the w3schools website after using the "try it out" editor so I know it's supposed to work. When I changed the page from a page in their subdirectory to an external page, it shows up blank.

Comment: I read somewhere recently, sorry can't remember where, that google actively prevents some of it's sites working in iframes.

Comment: well for me, ANY url that I put, I don't see anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The syntax is correct. It's not your fault - Google is blocking iframing using the [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header) header that newer browsers listen to.

Possible workarounds are explained in [this Google forum post.](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Web+Search/thread?tid=7070a92c8b0b241d&hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, I should've tested with other websites.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instruction in the following Google Developer Site under "IFrame embeds using the IFrame Player API" bullet:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

This uses API's JavaScript code to view youtube videos.

Here's the link with a more general instruction
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player