# iframe does not load website from local network (but loads external sites fine)

Tags: iframe

I would like to embed a few local apps into a single website.

The code below successfully loads external sites but does not load apps running on the local network.

For example `http://app.local` loads when accessed from the browser directly but does not load when in the iframe.

```
html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://app.local" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why is this happening and how can I address it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iframes not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947144/iframes-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947144/iframes-not-working) could be a similar case. Are there any `X-Frame-Options` set on your app?
Also, are there any errors in your web-inspector ?